# La conversión especificada no es válida - Al intentar obtener Float con Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, visual-studio-2017, linq-to-sql

Muy buen día, tengo el siguiente error:

> "   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
>   \r\n   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
>   \r\n   en Read_FlowNode(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
>   \r\n   en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
>   \r\n   en System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>   \r\n   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   \r\n   en WF_FlowChart.Models.Configuration.FManagement.LoadFlow() en 
>       C:\Users\VICTOR\TFS_VP\WF_FlowChart\WF_FlowChart\Models\Configuration\FManagement.cs:línea 81"

Al intentar obtener registros de la base de datos:

```
FlowNodes = (from n in _db.FlowNodes
                             where n.IDFlow == Flow.ID && !n.Disable
                             select n).ToArray();
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
[Table(Name = "FLOWNODES")]
public class FlowNode
{
    [Column(Name = "ID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "IDFLOW")]
    public int IDFlow { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "IDFLOWTASK")]
    public int IDFlowTask { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "IDFLOWCONDITION")]
    public int IDFlowCondition { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "IDFLOWCONVERGENCE")]
    public int IDFlowConvergence { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "NODEKIND")]
    public int NodeKind { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "POINTX")]
    public float PointX { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "POINTY")]
    public float PointY { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DISABLE")]
    public bool Disable { get; set; }
}
```

Por lo que he leído tiene que ver con el tipo Float, pero no lo he podido resolver. De ante mano gracias.

Comment: Podrias colocar la estructura de tu tabla, especificamente los tipos de datos que declaras a cada uno de los campos de la tabla. Por que el error habla sobre `GetInt32`. Seguro que algunas de la propiedades que defines como int no es un int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado!

Lo que pasó en mi caso eran 2 cosas:
 - NodeKind es de tipo `SMALLINT` en la base de datos y lo quería obtener como `int` en C#; Lo cambié a `short`.
 - Los campos PointX y PointY en base de datos son `FLOAT` y en C# igual `float`, pero por alguna razón la clase necesita que se especifique que el tipo es `FLOAT`.

La tabla en base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE FLOWNODES
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    IDFLOW INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    IDFLOWTASK INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    IDFLOWCONDITION INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    IDFLOWCONVERGENCE INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    NODEKIND SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    POINTX FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    POINTY FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    DISABLE BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

Mi modelo quedó así:

```
[Table(Name = "FLOWNODES")]
public class FlowNode
{
    [Column(Name = "ID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "IDFLOW")]
        public int IDFlow { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "IDFLOWTASK")]
        public int IDFlowTask { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "IDFLOWCONDITION")]
        public int IDFlowCondition { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "IDFLOWCONVERGENCE")]
        public int IDFlowConvergence { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "NODEKIND")]
        public short NodeKind { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "POINTX", DbType = "FLOAT")]
        public float PointX { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "POINTY", DbType = "FLOAT")]
        public float PointY { get; set; }
        [Column(Name = "DISABLE")]
        public bool Disable { get; set; }
}
```